Any difference among different shallow copy methods for list?
When I have a list a, I can create a shallow copy of a by the following four different methods:
a = [1, 2, 3]

b = list(a)
b = a.copy()
b = a[:]

import copy
b = copy.copy(a)

Here, I am wondering whether they always give the same result b, or possibly are there some cases (of a) that may give different results for b? (I guess performance may be different between the above methods, but here I am interested in the value of b rather than computational efficiency.)

no. no there are no differences in the semantics here. note, copy.copy just calls list.copy

@juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks very much! (I'm now preparing some intro note for list, but was not sure about the above behavior...) Good to know that copy.copy <=> list.copy also. I will accept your comment as answer if posted (or I will attach self-answer if no answer appears)
